# (selector).attr doesn't work in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

my code works in mozilla but not in chrome browser.

what is the solution?

my code (using jquery latest version):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#busd").click(function () {
        $("#unit").attr('name','busdUnit')
    })
    $("#bnb").click(function () {
        $("#unit").attr('name','bnbUnit')
    })
})
```

Comment: it seems working https://jsfiddle.net/p6m1vdaq/ maybe check if the item #unit has the id u described

Comment: yes but the ids "#busd" and "#bnb" are from select options

Comment: can u show the html structure?

Comment: @Weber
this is the link and BNB Just works perfect in firefox, not in chrome
https://jsfiddle.net/kmqwth0r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on your html you can't set a click event on the select option so u need to set a change event on the select and get the the attribute id for set it as attribute where needed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myselect").on('change',function(){
      var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
      $("#unit").attr('name',id);
     });
})
```

Comment: again it doesn't work in google chrome.
can you give a jsfiddle link?

Comment: here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g7cbw0ze/

Comment: Dear @Weber, unfortunately it doesn't work in chrome. I can record a video and show it to you. I guess this is a weak point for chromium browsers, or maybe the strength one.
but anyway it is not working.

Comment: @SaeedTJ did u add the id on select? like <select id="myselect">... however why work in js fiddle with chrome browser and not on your site

Comment: I just ran your code on jsfiddle.net and it didn't work. (without changing anything) :|
the browsers which I tested are Chrome and Edge.

Comment: See there i'm also using chrome and work everything look better at the code and see the differences in js and html https://jsfiddle.net/bcq4ygh1/1/